# RegEx not working. No matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to try and extract the last download speed in this string. I know it is followed by a SUMMARY.

This is my current RegEx:

```
/.*\s(\d+\.\d+\s[kB|MB|GB]\/s)\nSUMMARY.*/
```

This is the string:

> ```
>  7% [###                                           ] ETA:  0:00:12   1.99 MB/s
> 11% [#####                                         ] ETA:  0:00:08   2.87 MB/s
> 16% [#######                                       ] ETA:  0:00:06   3.39 MB/s
> 20% [#########                                     ] ETA:  0:00:05   4.04 MB/s
> 24% [##########                                    ] ETA:  0:00:04   4.61 MB/s
> 28% [#############                                 ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.41 MB/s
> 32% [##############                                ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.47 MB/s
> 36% [################                              ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.26 MB/s
> 40% [##################                            ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.26 MB/s
> 44% [####################                          ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.62 MB/s
> 49% [######################                        ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.88 MB/s
> 53% [########################                      ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.33 MB/s
> 57% [#########################                     ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.49 MB/s
> 61% [###########################                   ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.87 MB/s
> 65% [#############################                 ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.17 MB/s
> 69% [###############################               ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.44 MB/s
> 73% [#################################             ] ETA:  0:00:00   7.71 MB/s
> 77% [##################################            ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.10 MB/s
> 81% [####################################          ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.37 MB/s  
> 86% [######################################        ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.78 MB/s  
> 90% [########################################      ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.04 MB/s
> 94% [##########################################    ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.39 MB/s  
> 99% [############################################  ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.99 MB/s 
> 100% [#############################################] Time: 0:00:02   9.02 MB/s 
>
> SUMMARY: [32mSuccessfully downloaded[0m: 1
> ```

Comment: Use `/(\d+\.\d+\s(kB|MB|GB)\/s)\n\s*SUMMARY/.exec(s)[1]`

Comment: The entire array is null. Nothing is matching

Comment: That means the line endings are CR or CRLF. Try `/(\d+\.\d+\s(kB|MB|GB)\/s)(?:\r\n?|\n)\s*SUMMARY/.exec(s)[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems in your regex. Here's a fixed one:

```
/\s(\d+\.\d+\s+(kB|MB|GB)\/s)[\s\n\r]+SUMMARY/
```

```js
var str = document.querySelector("pre").textContent;
console.log(str.match(/\s(\d+\.\d+\s+(?:kB|MB|GB)\/s)[\s\n\r]+SUMMARY/));
```

```html
<pre>
7% [###                                          ] ETA:  0:00:10   2.27 MB/s
 11% [#####                                        ] ETA:  0:00:07   2.93 MB/s
 15% [#######                                      ] ETA:  0:00:05   3.73 MB/s
 19% [########                                     ] ETA:  0:00:04   4.34 MB/s
 23% [##########                                   ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.00 MB/s
 27% [############                                 ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.61 MB/s
 32% [##############                               ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.56 MB/s
 36% [################                             ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.77 MB/s
 40% [##################                           ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.80 MB/s
 44% [####################                         ] ETA:  0:00:02   6.00 MB/s
 48% [#####################                        ] ETA:  0:00:02   6.34 MB/s
 52% [#######################                      ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.74 MB/s
 56% [#########################                    ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.01 MB/s
 60% [###########################                  ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.30 MB/s
 64% [#############################                ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.69 MB/s
 68% [###############################              ] ETA:  0:00:01   8.11 MB/s
 73% [#################################            ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.50 MB/s
 77% [###################################          ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.75 MB/s
 82% [#####################################        ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.25 MB/s
 86% [#######################################      ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.53 MB/s
 91% [#########################################    ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.89 MB/s
 95% [##########################################   ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.09 MB/s
 99% [############################################ ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.10 MB/s
100% [#############################################] Time: 0:00:02   9.11 MB/s

SUMMARY:
</pre>
```

Note that:

- there was more than one new line, it's also prudent to not exclude other kind of spaces here, and to allow `\r`
- to do (A or B) you do `(A|B)`, not `[A|B]`.
- There's no reason to have `.*` at ends

Comment: This was short and concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive look-ahead to match the last file size before the summary.

```
(?=\s+SUMMARY)
```

***Note:** Don't forget to enable multi-line matching with the `m` flag at the end of the regex.*

```js
var text = document.getElementById('progress-log').innerHTML.trim();
var regex = /\d+\.\d{2} [kMGTP]B\/s(?=\s+SUMMARY)/m;

console.log('Final size:', text.match(regex)[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
#progress-log { display: none; }
```

```html
<pre id="progress-log">
 7% [###                                           ] ETA:  0:00:12   1.99 MB/s
11% [#####                                         ] ETA:  0:00:08   2.87 MB/s
16% [#######                                       ] ETA:  0:00:06   3.39 MB/s
20% [#########                                     ] ETA:  0:00:05   4.04 MB/s
24% [##########                                    ] ETA:  0:00:04   4.61 MB/s
28% [#############                                 ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.41 MB/s
32% [##############                                ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.47 MB/s
36% [################                              ] ETA:  0:00:03   5.26 MB/s
40% [##################                            ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.26 MB/s
44% [####################                          ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.62 MB/s
49% [######################                        ] ETA:  0:00:02   5.88 MB/s
53% [########################                      ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.33 MB/s
57% [#########################                     ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.49 MB/s
61% [###########################                   ] ETA:  0:00:01   6.87 MB/s
65% [#############################                 ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.17 MB/s
69% [###############################               ] ETA:  0:00:01   7.44 MB/s
73% [#################################             ] ETA:  0:00:00   7.71 MB/s
77% [##################################            ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.10 MB/s
81% [####################################          ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.37 MB/s  
86% [######################################        ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.78 MB/s  
90% [########################################      ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.04 MB/s
94% [##########################################    ] ETA:  0:00:00   9.39 MB/s  
99% [############################################  ] ETA:  0:00:00   8.99 MB/s 
100% [#############################################] Time: 0:00:02   9.02 MB/s 

SUMMARY: [32mSuccessfully downloaded[0m: 1
</pre>
```

> *Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.* — ([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the first .* with `.*?` and the second with `[\s\S].*`? That should work for multiline matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try: /\d+.\d+\s[MGK]B/s\n\nSUMMARY/  - there are two newline characters before 'SUMMARY'.